# npm install throws unexpected token error

Tags: npm

In my repo directory, when I try `npm install`, I'm getting this error: `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 3035`. I also get the same error when trying `npm uninstall [package]`. Any ideas what might be causing this? I'm on the latest version of npm.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `npm` registry used is still valid and you can access it. One place the `npm` registry information is stored is `~/.npmrc`. If you are not sure if the registry specified in `.npmrc` is valid, you may remove the registry information from this file (please ensure others don't need it if this is a shared system) and `npm` will use the default registry.